# Thunderbird template

Tags: thunderbird, templates

I have just started to use TB.
When I create a template within an email account, every reply or new message uses that template.
I don't want that.

Edit: it appears that even with the templates removed, new emails open with that template. Why is that?

My questions are:

- Is it possible to choose whether to use a template or not?
- Is it possible to have several templates and use one of them for answering or creating email?

Any suggestions to get me in the right direction are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native Thunderbird capability to cause compose to default to writing a new message from a template. This sounds like the remains of some add-on.

Try starting Thunderbird in safe mode https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/safe-mode-thunderbird

Comment: Thanks @wsmwk. I have managed to change the account settings